# How could this UPSERT query be made shorter?

Tags: postgresql, update, upsert

I have a table storing the result of some simulations.

Besides the few columns that identity the row, every single column in the row is getting replaced at each update.

The query feels quite long and repetitive:

```
INSERT INTO simulation.{tableName}
(
    stream, ticker, intervals, ts_start, ts_end,
    initial_margin, order_pairs, wins, losses, avg_win, avg_loss, max_consecutive_wins, max_consecutive_losses,
    gain_factor_count, avg_winning_position_duration, avg_losing_position_duration,
    f_gain_factor_notional, f_profits, f_fees, f_margin, f_relative_drawdown, f_absolute_drawdown, f_realized_profit, f_realized_fees_paid, f_weekly_upnl,
    c_gain_factor_notional, c_profits, c_fees, c_margin, c_relative_drawdown, c_absolute_drawdown, c_realized_profit, c_realized_fees_paid, c_weekly_upnl
)
VALUES
(
    @stream, @ticker, @intervals, @ts_start, @ts_end,
    @initial_margin, @order_pairs, @wins, @losses, @avg_win, @avg_loss, @max_consecutive_wins, @max_consecutive_losses,
    @gain_factor_count, @avg_winning_position_duration, @avg_losing_position_duration,
    @f_gain_factor_notional, @f_profits, @f_fees, @f_margin, @f_relative_drawdown, @f_absolute_drawdown, @f_realized_profit, @f_realized_fees_paid, @f_weekly_upnl,
    @c_gain_factor_notional, @c_profits, @c_fees, @c_margin, @c_relative_drawdown, @c_absolute_drawdown, @c_realized_profit, @c_realized_fees_paid, @c_weekly_upnl
)
ON CONFLICT (stream, ticker, intervals)
DO UPDATE
SET (
    stream, ticker, intervals, ts_start, ts_end,
    initial_margin, order_pairs, wins, losses, avg_win, avg_loss, max_consecutive_wins, max_consecutive_losses,
    gain_factor_count, avg_winning_position_duration, avg_losing_position_duration,
    f_gain_factor_notional, f_profits, f_fees, f_margin, f_relative_drawdown, f_absolute_drawdown, f_realized_profit, f_realized_fees_paid, f_weekly_upnl,
    c_gain_factor_notional, c_profits, c_fees, c_margin, c_relative_drawdown, c_absolute_drawdown, c_realized_profit, c_realized_fees_paid, c_weekly_upnl
) =
(
    @stream, @ticker, @intervals, @ts_start, @ts_end,
    @initial_margin, @order_pairs, @wins, @losses, @avg_win, @avg_loss, @max_consecutive_wins, @max_consecutive_losses,
    @gain_factor_count, @avg_winning_position_duration, @avg_losing_position_duration,
    @f_gain_factor_notional, @f_profits, @f_fees, @f_margin, @f_relative_drawdown, @f_absolute_drawdown, @f_realized_profit, @f_realized_fees_paid, @f_weekly_upnl,
    @c_gain_factor_notional, @c_profits, @c_fees, @c_margin, @c_relative_drawdown, @c_absolute_drawdown, @c_realized_profit, @c_realized_fees_paid, @c_weekly_upnl
)
```

Is there a way to make it less verbose / repetitive?

Comment: This query seems to be a part of some application source code. You only type it once; what's wrong with it being verbose?

Comment: @mustaccio, any update is very error prone when you have duplication like that. I have seen many times code failing in similar situation because one field was updated in some place but not some other place. If there was a way to say: overwrite the whole row, we'd eliminate 50% of the characters.

Comment: You're just trading one kind of errors for another, when your table's DDL subtly changes and your "concise" statement errors out or, worse, stores values in the wrong columns. Choose your poison, I guess.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I'll be back in the office next week, I'll look in depth then

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

> every single column in the row is getting replaced

So there is potential to shorten the code:

```
INSERT INTO simulation.tableName  -- ①
VALUES (
   @stream, @ticker, @intervals, @ts_start, @ts_end,
   @initial_margin, @order_pairs, @wins, @losses, @avg_win, @avg_loss, @max_consecutive_wins, @max_consecutive_losses,
   @gain_factor_count, @avg_winning_position_duration, @avg_losing_position_duration,
   @f_gain_factor_notional, @f_profits, @f_fees, @f_margin, @f_relative_drawdown, @f_absolute_drawdown, @f_realized_profit, @f_realized_fees_paid, @f_weekly_upnl,
   @c_gain_factor_notional, @c_profits, @c_fees, @c_margin, @c_relative_drawdown, @c_absolute_drawdown, @c_realized_profit, @c_realized_fees_paid, @c_weekly_upnl
   )
ON CONFLICT (stream, ticker, intervals)
DO UPDATE
SET (
   stream, ticker, intervals, ts_start, ts_end,
   initial_margin, order_pairs, wins, losses, avg_win, avg_loss, max_consecutive_wins, max_consecutive_losses,
   gain_factor_count, avg_winning_position_duration, avg_losing_position_duration,
   f_gain_factor_notional, f_profits, f_fees, f_margin, f_relative_drawdown, f_absolute_drawdown, f_realized_profit, f_realized_fees_paid, f_weekly_upnl,
   c_gain_factor_notional, c_profits, c_fees, c_margin, c_relative_drawdown, c_absolute_drawdown, c_realized_profit, c_realized_fees_paid, c_weekly_upnl
   ) =
ROW(EXCLUDED.*); -- ②
```

**①** Since, by definition, **all** columns are replaced, you *can* skip the target column list for the insert. The command works as long as provided values can be filled in from left to right. (Does not even have to be the complete column list, you just cannot skip any leading columns.)
**Though**, if this is persisted code, and there is a chance the table definition might change later (the common case!), it's typically safer to spell out all columns here.

**②** [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) allows two more syntax variants to provide values in the `SET` clause for the "column-list syntax": a sub-`SELECT` or `ROW()` expression. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.10)

> According to the standard, the source value for a parenthesized
> sub-list of target column names can be any row-valued expression
> yielding the correct number of columns. PostgreSQL only allows the
> source value to be a row constructor or a sub-`SELECT`. An individual
> column's updated value can be specified as `DEFAULT` in the
> [row-constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) case, but not inside a sub-`SELECT`.

The keyword `ROW` must be spelled out in this context to disambiguate (while it's optional noise in other contexts).

The special **`EXCLUDED`** table is used to reference values originally proposed for insertion. There is a subtle semantic difference, though. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

> Note that the effects of all per-row `BEFORE INSERT` triggers are
> reflected in excluded values, since those effects may have contributed
> to the row being excluded from insertion.

It's generally preferable to reference the special row `EXCLUDED` instead of spelling out all input values again. If you have any triggers as mentioned, it might even be a necessity.

Again, for persisted code, it may be safer to spell out all columns, but it's typically best to use the `EXCLUDED` table either way:

```
...
SET (
   stream, ticker, intervals, ts_start, ...
   ) =
    (EXCLUDED.stream, EXCLUDED.ticker, EXCLUDED.intervals, EXCLUDED.ts_start, ...)
```

You can still make it shorter with a sub-`SELECT`:

```
...
SET (
   stream, ticker, intervals, ts_start, ...
   ) =
=  (SELECT stream, ticker, intervals, ts_start, ...
    FROM (SELECT EXCLUDED.*) e)
```